# Rcording Audio At a certain level visual c++ 2008(32 bit)

Tags: visual-c++, audio-recording

I'm trying to make a program that record audio from an input audio device (expample: microphone)
but only when the signal is active (means only when some one is talking in the mic)
and save it as mp3 format
and i tried but it is so hard please help me

Answer (score 0):

I know of a way to accomplish this, although I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it: this will not necessarily be easy if you are not familiar with DirectShow as it requires you to learn many aspects of the technology. You could use DirectShow to set up a media pipeline that looks roughly as follows:

Capture Source -> SampleGrabber -> Audio Renderer

This is a simple playback graph. In the sample grabber you can intercept samples as they pass through the pipeline. Here for example you could process the sample to see whether it is silence or not. When you've got that right, try setting up a graph that looks something like this

Capture Source -> SampleGrabber -> mp3 encoder -> filewriter

Not sure about the filewriter (if that works for mp3 encoded data): more homework for you.

Then using the [GMFBridge](http://www.gdcl.co.uk) you could set up multiple graphs.

1) Capture Source -> SampleGrabber -> GMFBridgeSink
2) GMFBridgeSource -> mp3 encoder -> filewriter
3) GMFBridgeSource -> renderer (or something)

GMFBridge allows you to switch between graphs dynamically during playback.
So 1) would typically be connected to 3) until you detect a certain level of audio, then bridges to 2). Once the audio level drops back to 3).

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it is *a* solution or starting point. Perhaps someone else can suggest another way. Good luck.

Comment: thank you i dont understand much of it because i'm new to v-c++ but i'll try to do it and thanks again if you now somebody to help please ask him to answer me.